Поиск двух и более слов в строке с помощью django-filter
В выведенном списке на странице есть возможность фильтровать с помощью django-filter.
Пример: строка адреса 'Оренбургская обл, г Бузулук, ул Чапаева, д 33'. Задаю "Чапаева" - находит; задаю "Чапаева 33" - нет.
В интернете нашел код фильтра:
class MyAddressFilter(filters.CharFilter):
    empty_value = 'EMPTY'

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value != self.empty_value:
            return super().filter(qs, value)

        qs = self.get_method(qs)(**{'%s__%s' % (self.field_name, self.lookup_expr): ""})
        return qs.distinct() if self.distinct else qs

Результат тот же. Как переписать этот данный код чтобы между поисковыми словами могло быть любое слово/символ? Желательно не ограничиваться 2мя словами/цифрами поиска.
